# PAM: Authentication failure, with valid password

Tags: pam

**Command**

```
pamtester -v auth pknopf authenticate
pamtester: invoking pam_start(auth, pknopf, ...)
pamtester: performing operation - authenticate
Password:
pamtester: Authentication failure
```

**journctl**

```
Feb 06 13:22:17 PAULS-ARCH unix_chkpwd[31998]: check pass; user unknown
Feb 06 13:22:17 PAULS-ARCH unix_chkpwd[31998]: password check failed for user (pknopf)
Feb 06 13:22:17 PAULS-ARCH pamtester[31997]: pam_unix(auth:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=1000 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=pknopf
```

As it stands right now, every lock screen will prevent me from "unlocking" (KDE lock screen, `i3lock`, etc).

If I start `i3lock` as `sudo`, I can then properly type in the *root* password to unlock the screen. However, if I run it as normal user, and I can't use normal user or root password to unlock.

Here is my PAM config for `i3lock`.

```
#
# PAM configuration file for the i3lock screen locker. By default, it includes
# the 'system-auth' configuration file (see /etc/pam.d/login)
#
auth include system-auth
```

Running `ls -l /etc/passwd /etc/shadow /etc/group` shows

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 803 Feb 6 14:16 /etc/group
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1005 Feb 6 14:16 /etc/passwd
-rw------- 1 root root 713 Feb 6 14:16 /etc/shadow
```

This is a fresh install of Arch, so I don't think the configuration is too wonky. What should I be looking for to debug this?

Running `ls -l /sbin/unix_chkpwd` shows

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 31392 Jun  9  2016 /sbin/unix_chkpwd
```

Comment: You've a user account `pknopf` in your `/etc/passwd`, etc., and it can log in?

Comment: My account is in /etc/passwd.

Comment: I can "pamtester auth pknopf authenticate" with (running as) root user, but not with pknopf user.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your system installation appears to be broken. For some reason, the file `/sbin/unix_chkpwd` has lost the privilege bits I would expect to see.

Fix the permissions by running the following command as root:

```
chmod u+s /sbin/unix_chkpwd
```

And verify the permissions are now as follows (see the `s` bit in the user permissions):

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 31392 Jun  9  2016 /sbin/unix_chkpwd
```

---

On my Raspbian distribution the permissions are set slightly differently (and more restrictively). If the change described above does not work, *carefully* change the permissions on these two files and see if this helps (the group name does not matter too much as long as it's the same in both cases):

```
-rw-r----- 1 root shadow  1354 Dec  6 13:02 /etc/shadow
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root shadow 30424 Mar 27  2017 /sbin/unix_chkpwd
```

Comment: This as my issue. It was a result of Docker stripping that privilege bit.

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36239

Answer (score 4):

On a Debian machine, in my case I had to add exim4 user to the `shadow` group.

```
usermod -a -G shadow Debian-exim
```

> PAM: On Debian systems the PAM modules run as the same user as the
>   calling program, so they cannot do anything you could not do yourself,
>   and in particular cannot access /etc/shadow unless the user is in
>   group shadow. - If you want to use /etc/shadow for Exim's SMTP AUTH
>   you will need to run exim as group shadow. Only exim4-daemon-heavy is
>   linked against libpam. We suggest using saslauthd instead.

http://lira.no-ip.org:8080/doc/exim4-base/README.Debian.html

Comment: This would create a huge security concern.

Comment: Please elaborate, and provide an alternative @KongChunHo

Comment: Adding a service user `Debian-exim` to shadow group allows an attacker read `/etc/shadow` which contains (hashed) password of the machine when the service is compromised. I do not have an alternative solution, but I just want to point out the security implications.

Comment: So really this is the right solution.

Comment: This maybe the right solution, but definitely *not a safe solution* in security standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, but additionally had to fix the permission of the

```
chmod u+s /bin/sudo
chmod u+s /sbin/unix_chkpwd
chmod u+s /usr/bin/su
```

Error was

```
unix_chkpwd[37679]: password check failed for user XXX
su: pam_unix(su-l:auth): authentication failure;
```